# Does modifying an order cancel the old one and submit a new one

Tags: stock-markets, limit-order

Suppose XYZ is trading at 25$. If I submit a limit buy order for XYZ stock at 20$, and let us say my order goes to the top of the order book.

5 min later, I 'modify' the order and make it 22$. Will I retain my top position in the order book? Or will it cancel the old order and submit a new order? Is it brokerage dependent?

Comment: Why don't you ask the broker this?

Comment: If buy/$20 is at the top of the book, why would you think $22 would be lower? Of course it's still top, provided no other orders were placed.

Comment: Not sure why this is down-voted. It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit books are managed by exchanges.

If an order is not immediately filled, it is sent to the book.  From there, orders are generally executed on price-time-priority.  The one major exception is the precedence hide-not-slide orders have over earlier placed visible slidden limit orders since unslidden orders are treated like a modification/cancellation.

To an exchange, a modification is the same as a cancellation since it charges no fees for placing or canceling orders, only for trades.  The timestamp is reset, and price-time-priority is applied in the same way, so if a modified order isn't immediately filled, it is sent back to the book to be filled in order of price-time-priority.

Comment: " a modification is the same as a cancellation"...that was what I was looking for...thank you

Comment: Note that this is only true if you modify to change price. If you modify to lower the size of your order, on many exchanges you keep time priority. A size increase will also send you to the back.